# How can I configure an application in wildfly outside the deployment artefact

Tags: wildfly

I want to deploy an application to wildfly and want to be able to configure this application with data that is not contained in the ear/war file. I want to be able to deploy the same application on different wildfly instances but have different configurations.

In Glassfish I have the possibility to configure custom JNDI properties which can be injected in my app with the `@Resource`annotation and which are mapped to a properties object.

What possibilities does Wildfly offer for application configuration?

One possibility I can think of is to put some file in the configuration directory and directly read this file. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

> In Glassfish I have the possibility to configure custom JNDI properties which can be injected in my app with the `@Resource` annotation and which are mapped to a properties object.

[The same exists for Wildfly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JNDI+Reference)

Basically, on your `standalone.xml`, under the `naming` subsystem, inside `bindings`, add something like this:

```
<simple name="java:global/jbossDocs" value="https://docs.jboss.org" type="java.net.URL" />
```